# How can we work on Oracle 10g at localhost

Tags: oracle10g

i am new in Oracle 10g.  I want to work on localhost in oracle 10g.  I have use scott/tiger and it also demand hostname.  I have used their my pc name `localhost` but it didn't work.

when i use scott as user name and tiger as password and dont give any host name then its give me an error "ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

I have found this code in that file tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\DevSuiteHome_2\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

```
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS =
        (PROTOCOL = TCP)
        (HOST=Zainy-PC)
        (PORT = 1521)
      )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME=DIV01)
    )
  )
```

and i am using Windows 7 platform.....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is not a programming problem, but a "using the software" problem.  I have voted to move this question to superuser.com where you would likely get an answer.  However, you should add what "doesn't work" means:  was there an error message?  Did it hang?  Is there a `scott/tiger` account on the server?

Comment: when i use scott as user name and tiger as password and dont give any host name then its give me an error  "ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

Comment: Can you post your TNSNames.ora and listener.ora files (they are in [oracle home]/network/admin

Comment: I have found this code in that file                  # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\DevSuiteHome_2\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST=Zainy-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME=DIV01)
    )
  )                    and i am using Windows 7 platform.....

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting with DIV01 as host name

Answer (score 0):

http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex

http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4550:11:480290067487773::NO:::

username:system

password: 'what you entered while installation'